# Need to merge 2 large csv files row by row in python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, memory-management

I am processing 2 large data set files for a project. I managed the clean the files row by row. However on trying to apply the same logic to merge the 2 files based on a common column, it fails. The problem is that the second loop runs completely and then the top loop runs(don't know why this happened). I tried using numpy

```
buys = np.genfromtxt('buys_dtsep.dat',delimiter=",",dtype='str')
clicks = np.genfromtxt('clicks_dtsep.dat',delimiter=",",dtype='str')
f = open('combined.dat', 'w')
for s in clicks:
    for s2 in buys:
      #process data
```

but loading a file with 33 million entries into an array is not feasible due to memory restrictions and the time it would take to load the data into an array and then process it. I'm trying to process the files line by line to avoid running out of memory.

```
buys = open('buys_dtsep.dat')
clicks = open('clicks_dtsep.dat')
f = open('combined.dat', 'w')

csv_buys = csv.reader(buys)
csv_clicks = csv.reader(clicks)



for s in csv_clicks:
     print 'file 1 row x'#to check when it loops
     for s2 in csv_buys:
        print s2[0] #check looped data  
          #do merge op
```

output of the print should be

```
file 1 row 0
file 2 row 0
 ...
file 2 row x
file 1 row 1
and so on
```

output i get is

```
file 2 row 0
file 2 row 1
...
file 2 row x
file 1 row 0
...
file 1 row z
```

if the above looping issue can be resolved, ill be able to merge the files row by row.

Updated: Sample data

buys file sample

```
420374,2014-04-06,18:44:58.314,214537888,12462,1
420374,2014-04-06,18:44:58.325,214537850,10471,1
281626,2014-04-06,09:40:13.032,214535653,1883,1
420368,2014-04-04,06:13:28.848,214530572,6073,1
420368,2014-04-04,06:13:28.858,214835025,2617,1
140806,2014-04-07,09:22:28.132,214668193,523,1
140806,2014-04-07,09:22:28.176,214587399,1046,1
```

clicks file sample

```
420374,2014-04-06,18:44:58,214537888,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:41:50,214537888,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:42:33,214537850,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:42:38,214537850,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:43:02,214537888,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:43:10,214537888,0
420369,2014-04-07,19:39:43,214839373,0
420369,2014-04-07,19:39:56,214684513,0
```

Comment: Could you use `pandas` for that? If yes you could consider `read_csv` with `chunks` argument like in [that](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk) example

Comment: Could you add a handful of sample rows from the two dat files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach will hopefully help. It is designed to be faster and reduce your memory requirements:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby, ifilter

def get_click_entries(key):
    with open('clicks.csv', 'rb') as f_clicks:
        for entry in ifilter(lambda x: int(x[0]) == key, csv.reader(f_clicks)):
            entry.insert(4, '')  # add empty missing column
            yield entry

# First create a set holding all column 0 click entries

with open('clicks.csv', 'rb') as f_clicks:
    csv_clicks = csv.reader(f_clicks)
    click_keys = {int(cols[0]) for cols in csv_clicks}

with open('buys.csv', 'rb') as f_buys, \
    open('clicks.csv', 'rb') as f_clicks,   \
    open('merged.csv', 'wb') as f_merged:

    csv_buys = csv.reader(f_buys)
    csv_clicks = csv.reader(f_clicks)
    csv_merged = csv.writer(f_merged)

    for k, g in groupby(csv_buys, key=lambda x: int(x[0])):
        if k in click_keys:
            buys = sorted(g, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2]))
            clicks = sorted(get_click_entries(k), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2]))
            csv_merged.writerows(merge(buys, clicks))       # merge the two lists based on the timestamp
            click_keys.remove(k)
        csv_merged.writerows(g)

    # Write any remaining click entries

    for k in click_keys:
        csv_merged.writerows(get_click_entries(k))
```

For your two sample files, this would produce the following output:

```
140806,2014-04-07,09:22:28.132,214668193,523,1
140806,2014-04-07,09:22:28.176,214587399,1046,1
281626,2014-04-06,09:40:13.032,214535653,1883,1
420368,2014-04-04,06:13:28.848,214530572,6073,1
420368,2014-04-04,06:13:28.858,214835025,2617,1
420374,2014-04-06,18:41:50,214537888,,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:42:33,214537850,,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:42:38,214537850,,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:43:02,214537888,,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:43:10,214537888,,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:44:58,214537888,,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:44:58.314,214537888,12462,1
420374,2014-04-06,18:44:58.325,214537850,10471,1
420369,2014-04-07,19:39:43,214839373,,0
420369,2014-04-07,19:39:56,214684513,,0
```

It works by first creating a set of all of the column 0 entries, this then means you can avoid rereading the whole click file if it is known that the entry is not present. It then attempts to read in a group of matching column 0 entries from `buys`, and reads in a corresponding list of column 0 entries from `clicks`. These are then sorted based on the timestamp and merged together in order. This entry is then removed from the set so they are not reread.

Comment: I liked your methodology, however wont creating a set take very long, given that i have approx 33 million entries in one data set and a few million in the other? I shall try this solution too and post the results. Thanks

Comment: You need to reread clicks each loop, so creating a set once will not take much longer, and will then avoid many unnecessary rereads. I have assumed that neither file can fit in memory.

Comment: Thank You. I tried your method partially. It works very well :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The OP wants to all over the 2nd file so I changed my answer

You are looping over the 1st line in the first file and then looping all over the 2nd.
Your inner loop will only work once since csv_buys iterator will be consumed in the first run of the 1st loop.

```
for s in csv_clicks:  # <--- looping over the 1st file works fine
    print 'file 1 row x'#to check when it loops
    for s2 in csv_buys: #<--- loops all over the 2nd one and finish the iterator! this loop will ONLY work once!
        print s2[0] #check looped data  
         #do merge op
```

What you need to do is:

```
for s in csv_clicks:  # <--- stays the same - works fine
    print 'file 1 row x'#to check when it loops
    for s2 in open('buys_dtsep.dat'): #<---- Now you loop from the start each time :) yay
        print s2[0] #check looped data  
         #do merge op
```

WARNING: The code above has complexity of O^2.

If your script will be very slow (and it will) you'll have to think of a different solution

Comment: i need to check if a match for say column 1 of row i in file 1 is found in any row of file 2 so as to make a merged file. Thats why i nested the loops. Ill try using the above method to do the same

Comment: @duckvader - Changed my answer to loop over the 2nd file each time

Comment: the new solution allows me to access how I need to. Thank you. Although its slow, i'll work on it till i find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced file to StringIO for example. With file object code looks same.

```
import  StringIO

file1 = StringIO.StringIO("""420374,2014-04-06,18:44:58.314,214537888,12462,1
420374,2014-04-06,18:44:58.325,214537850,10471,1
281626,2014-04-06,09:40:13.032,214535653,1883,1
420368,2014-04-04,06:13:28.848,214530572,6073,1
420368,2014-04-04,06:13:28.858,214835025,2617,1
140806,2014-04-07,09:22:28.132,214668193,523,1
140806,2014-04-07,09:22:28.176,214587399,1046,1""")

file2 = StringIO.StringIO("""420374,2014-04-06,18:44:58,214537888,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:41:50,214537888,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:42:33,214537850,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:42:38,214537850,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:43:02,214537888,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:43:10,214537888,0
420369,2014-04-07,19:39:43,214839373,0
420369,2014-04-07,19:39:56,214684513,0""")

outfile = StringIO.StringIO()

data1_iter, skip_1 = iter(file1), False
data2_iter, skip_2 = iter(file2), False

while True:
    out = []
    if not skip_1:
        try:
            out.append(next(data1_iter).split()[0])
        except StopIteration:
            skip_1 = True
    if not skip_2:
        try:
            out.append(next(data2_iter).split()[0])
        except StopIteration:
            skip_2 = True            

    outfile.write('\n'.join(out) + "\n")
    if skip_1 and skip_2:
        break

print(outfile.getvalue())
```

Output:

```
420374,2014-04-06,18:44:58.314,214537888,12462,1
420374,2014-04-06,18:44:58,214537888,0
420374,2014-04-06,18:44:58.325,214537850,10471,1
420374,2014-04-06,18:41:50,214537888,0
281626,2014-04-06,09:40:13.032,214535653,1883,1
420374,2014-04-06,18:42:33,214537850,0
420368,2014-04-04,06:13:28.848,214530572,6073,1
420374,2014-04-06,18:42:38,214537850,0
420368,2014-04-04,06:13:28.858,214835025,2617,1
420374,2014-04-06,18:43:02,214537888,0
140806,2014-04-07,09:22:28.132,214668193,523,1
420374,2014-04-06,18:43:10,214537888,0
140806,2014-04-07,09:22:28.176,214587399,1046,1
420369,2014-04-07,19:39:43,214839373,0
420369,2014-04-07,19:39:56,214684513,0
```